# Why does TF-IDF work in TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, text-mining, tfidf

As I understand TF-IDF, the IDF value of the word "art" = log_e(3/1) + 1 because there are 3 documents in the data set and the word "art" appears once. But after I use the print IDF from the vetorizer.idf_ function, the IDF value of "art" is ~2.098612 but when the function calculates it is 1.693147
And one more question: I calculated the TF value for the word "art" in data 1, which is equal to 0.125 because it appears once in a total of 8 words. Is my calculation correct like the TfidfVectirizer function?

This is my data and code

```
data = ['Souvenir shop|Architecture and art|Culture and history',
        'Souvenir shop|Resort|Diverse cuisine|Fishing|Shop games|Beautiful scenery',
        'Diverse cuisine|Resort|Beautiful scenery']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```